# WPF Unbound Custom object

Tags: c#, wpf, bind, datacontext

here's my problem:

I have a CustomObj with the INotifyPropertyChanged implemented, an UserControl and a Window, both will use that CustomObj as DataContext. In the UserControl there's an edit button that when clicked opens an Edit window for the CustomObj, with the ShowDialog native method.

My problem is that I want to edit the CustomObj in my Window and only reflect the changes on my UserControl if the user clicks "Save", on the other hand if the user clicks "Cancel", no changes are made to the CustomObj in the UserControl.

What is happening is that when I pass the CustomObj to the Window as an argument (I pass it to the Window constructor) is still bound to the CustomObj in the UserControl, and so, all the changes that I make in the Window are immediately reflected on the object in my UserControl.

I've tried to instantiate a new object, unbound the DataContext and nothing works... I don't want to Create a new CustomObj and rebuild each property since this object is a very complex and extensive one.

Is there a better way to do this??

Thanks

Comment: if your object is serializable.. you can "clone" it using serialization / deserialization. Otherwise, you'll have to mark all your bindings as `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` and traverse them when clicking save and call `.UpdateSource()`, which is ugly and sinful and bad. Post the relevant code. Questions asking about the "better way" to do stuff are either *Too Broad* or *Primarily Opinion Based* and thus off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Well... the object will eventually become serializable, but the project is not at that point yet. Guess I'll give it a try... The "better way" was just a nice way to ask for a different solution, but thanks, will be more clear next time. Thanks